# CSS webkit image mask not working

Tags: css, webkit, typography

I'm trying to follow some tutorials on applying masks but whenever I apply anything to my h1 all the text disappears completely. I've tried using image masks and gradients and the same thing happens.

```
<h1 id="site-name">
    <a href="/" title="Home"><span>The Biospheric Project</span></a>
</h1>
```

CSS using the gradient

```css
h1 { 
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)),
    to(rgba(0,0,0,.2)));
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(30, 28, 28, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is accessing your page using `file://` instead of `https://`

Firefox and Chrome (and maybe others) will silently fail when attempting to apply a mask if you access your HTML file using the `file://` protocol. You will instead see the entire CSS element masked out completely (i.e. it disappears, but it still occupies space on the screen). To fix it, you need to either open your page via `localhost://` (eg, using a local Apache server) or upload to your remote server and test it from there.

This is relatively annoying, given browsers can load images locally no problem using the `file://` protocol. A discussion on the [Mozilla bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565509) suggests that new features (such as `mask-image`) are being protected by CORS, but existing features (such as `<img src`) are not, but with no real rhyme or reason to it.

Comment: Relevant answer^ in 2020. Just served on a local server - masks load just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to work as is.

```
h1 { 
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)),
    to(rgba(0,0,0,.2)));
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(30, 28, 28, 0.6);
}
```

See this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/2crma/

Of course it can only work on webkit browsers.

Comment: I'm trying it on Chrome and Safari, and it doesn't display. It seems to display on other websites using that property - as it does on the fiddle site. I wonder if it is inheriting some other CSS property which is interfering with it? That fiddle site looks great for testing and working out where it's going wrong

Comment: Feel free to fiddle around! ;-) and +1 if you like.